# Exponential Function Expansion but with Double Factorials

Tags: combinatorics, taylor-expansion, power-series, exponential-function

Considering:  $\sum_n \frac{z^n}{n!}=e^{z}$

I was wondering if there is anything similar for: $\sum_{n:\text{ odd or even} }\frac{z^n}{n!!}$

That is, when you replace $n!$ with $n!!$ and add for all odd $n$'s or even $n$'s.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!!}=e^{\frac{z^2}{2}} \left(1+\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\,
   \text{erf}\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$ where appears the error function
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!!}=e^{\frac{z^2}{2}}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!!}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{\frac{z^2}{2}} \text{erf}\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you! I couldn’t find this no matter how much I searched. Is there some reference I can look at for the proof?